# Saber si una matriz esta en orden

Tags: python

El ejercicio propuesto esa saber si una matriz esta en orden ascendente por filas. No he sido capaz de descifrado como hacerlo.

El problema es que no soy capaz de pasar de una fila a otra y siga desde el numero de la anterior para que siga comparando.

la unica condicion es el orden por filas. por cada fila, se tiene que comparar cada valor, y de izquierda a derecha ser mayor que el otro y asi sucesivamente, con las demas filas como un todo. si pasa de una fila a otra, tiene que seguir comparando con el ultimo valor de la anterior.

Una matriz ordenada seria:

```
matriz = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]  
#o
matriz = [[1,4,7],[10,14,15],[21,22,30]
```

Una matriz desordenada seria:

```
matriz = [[1,3,2],[4,5,7],[10,9,8]
```

**importante**
una matriz que pareciera ordenada seria pero no es

```
matriz = [[10,11,12],[5,6,7],[1,2,3]]
```

Necesario que se mantenga el orden ascendente.
Con solo un numero que no sea mayor al anterior, ya no es ordenada

Esto es lo que llevo del código:

```
m1 = [[10,12,14],[15,20,18],[19,20,21]]
x = int(len(m1))
orden = True
for i in range (1,x):
    for j in range(1,x):
        
        ver = m1[i-1][j-1]
        ver2 = m1[i-1][j]
        
        if ver < ver2:
            orden = True
        else:
            orden = False
            break
        
if orden == False:
    print("No esta en orden")
else:
    print("Si esta en orden")
```

Comment: Buenas, puedes poner un ejemplo de la matriz desordenada y uno ordenado?

Comment: dices: *en orden ascendente por filas*, pero bajo que condición? la suma de sus valores? su primer valor? su segundo valor? el promedio? o que?

Comment: sabes sobre el algoritmo de ordenamiento burbuja?

Comment: @Christian si, pero no necesito ordenarlos, sino verificar que esten ordenados con las condiciones dadas

Comment: igual te puede servir, con el algoritmo burbuja comparas un par de datos y verificas si es uno es mayor que el otro, en caso no lo sea los cambias de lugar. Para tu caso solo deberas quedarte en la comparación y listo

Answer (score 0):

Esta función revisa si la lista está en orden ascendente:

```
def chequear(matriz):
    salida = [val for sublista in matriz for val in sublista]
    return salida == sorted(salida)
```

La primera instrucción *aplana* la lista, convirtiendo

```
[[10, 11, 12], [5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3]]
```

en

```
[10, 11, 12, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3]
```

Luego la ordenamos con `sorted` y comparamos el resultado contra la lista original. Si son iguales, quiere decir que ya estaba ordenada.

La comprensión de listas

```
[val for sublista in matriz for val in sublista]
```

es la manera compacta de escribir

```
for sublista in matriz:
    for val in sublista:
         val # Que vendría siendo incorporado a la nueva lista.
```

#### Demo

```
tests = [
    [[10,11,12],[5,6,7],[1,2,3]],
    [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],
    [[1,4,7],[10,14,15],[21,22,30]],
    [[10,12,14],[15,20,18],[19,20,21]]
    ]

for test in tests:
    if chequear(test):
        print(f"{test} está ordenada")
    else:
        print(f"{test} está desordenada")
```

produce

```
[[10, 11, 12], [5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3]] está desordenada
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] está ordenada
[[1, 4, 7], [10, 14, 15], [21, 22, 30]] está ordenada
[[10, 12, 14], [15, 20, 18], [19, 20, 21]] está desordenada

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Versión sin funciones

```
def chequear(matriz):
    salida = [val for sublista in matriz for val in sublista]
    for i in range(len(salida) - 1):
        if salida[i] > salida[i+1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: había pensado en esto pero creo que lo quiere hacer desde 0 (sin funciones de ayuda)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar algo como

```
def plain_matrix(matrix):
    for lst in matrix:
        yield from lst


def is_ordered(matrix):
    if len(matrix) > 0:
        plain = plain_matrix(matrix)
        last = next(plain)

        for e in plain:
            if e < last:
                return False

            last = e

        return True
    else:
        raise valueError('Matrix is empty')
```

Un caso de prueba sería

```
import pytest 

from solution import is_ordered

@pytest.mark.parametrize("matrix, expected", [
    ([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]], True),
    ([[1,4,7],[10,14,15],[21,22,30]], True),
    ([[1,3,2],[4,5,7],[10,9,8]], False),
    ([[10,11,12],[5,6,7],[1,2,3]], False)
])
def test_ordered_matrix(matrix, expected):
    assert is_ordered(matrix) == expected
```

Donde `plain_matrix` devuelve un iterador que permite terminar las comparaciones cuando la condición no se cumple.

Answer (score 0):

La forma fácil de hacer es recorriendo las lista y verificando si su elemento siguiente es mayor, al llegar al final de la lista guardaremos ese valor y luego lo comprobaremos con el primer elemento de la lista posterior, todo se resume  a 2 for anidados y algunos if.

```py
def verificar_orden(matriz):
    ultimo = None
    for lista in matriz:
        for n in range(len(lista)-1):
            #si el ultimo elemento es mayor al primera de la lista
            if ultimo and ultimo > lista[0]: return False #retornamos false
            #si el elemento es mayor que el sigueinte
            if lista[n] > lista[n+1]: return False #retornamos false
            #si estamos en la ultima iteracion
            if n+1 == len(lista)-1: ultimo = lista[-1] #guardamos el ultimo valor
    #si pasa todo
    return True #retornamos true
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma alternativa y más pitonica usando [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) y [any()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

```
def is_sort(m):
    tmp = [x for sublist in m for x in sublist]
    return all(list(x[0]<=x[1] for x in zip(tmp, tmp[1:])))
```

La primera instrucción aplana la lista:

```
m = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5...]
```

En la segunda instrucción se crea parejas del elemento actual con el siguiente, `(1, 2), (2, 3), etc` y se compara si el elemento `0` de cada pareja es menor al `1`. Si hay un solo elemento `False`, `all()` retornará False por lo que la lista no está ordenada ascendentemente.

```
print(is_sort([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])) # True
print(is_sort([[1,4,7],[10,14,15],[21,22,30]])) # True
print(is_sort([[1,3,2],[4,5,7],[10,9,8]])) # False
print(is_sort([[10,11,12],[5,6,7],[1,2,3]])) # False
```